# Got the Marshal badge - too easy

Tags: discussion, review, flags, badges

Once I looked up to profiles with the Marshal badge. They certainly must have made some sort of effort, I thought. Over a looong time. When I earned the Deputy bagde I was happy, a hard earned bagde for a serious effort.

But then I got the 10K tools. After a very little effort, rewieving the moderator queue for flagged posts once in a while, I earned the Marshal badge. It is the most easy earned badge I have earned next after Disciplined and Peer Pressure.

Is there some sort of logic of this I overlook? Also, only 910 have earned the Marshal badge by the time speaken. It looks strange to me.

Comment: The marshal badge is not about reviewing flags, it says: "raised 500 helpfull flags" .

Comment: Congratulations! You're one of the few users (as you noticed) who raised helpful flags and contributed to make Stack Overflow a better place. That badge is well-earned. Now, if you want a challenge, try [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/146/legendary). If you want a *real* challenge, try [that one](http://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/30/beta).

Comment: I'm not a 10K user and I also have.  Specifically, I have less than 3K, so I can just flag every off-topic post I find.

Comment: @Jamal, did so also, but with 10k tools you get a long list where you basically just have to say yes or no, making it too easy to earn the Marshal badge.

Comment: @davidkonrad I've added my downvote just for your attitude in the comments (on the answer below). Others may have downvoted because they disagree with your statement - that's how votes on meta work.

Comment: Rather than focusing just on badges, why not continue to contribute to the well-being of the site?  For example, I have over 3500 helpful flags on Arqade.  If you're only doing it for the badge, it's great that you helped out, but the real test is when you do it for no badges at all.

Comment: Well the 10k tools will be gone soon. So huzzah!

Comment: To summary : I raised a **question**. it is appearently very hard to understand. After being severe mocked on several questions and answers, I understand that the purpose of meta not is about "_meta-discussions of the Stack Exchange family of Q&A websites_" at all. It is about bullying those who has not yet seen the light. Think "meta" should be a little more positive and less judgmental.

Comment: I just got this badge and now I'm wondering whats next. Flagging every other post (sheesh) has become an ingrained habit now, so its a little disappointing the "game" ends here, and there isn't a prize for 1K helpful flags, or 2K, or 5k!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

By raising flags from the 10K queue, you are ([at least in principle](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue)) helping the site.

Therefore, the assertion that you have

> [Raised 500 helpful flags](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/160/marshal)

holds true.

Comment: @david, if it was *that* easy to raise 500 helpful flags, don't you think more than 910 users would have earned that badge?

Comment: Well, it was very easy to me. You just get a list which basically is yes or no.

Comment: @davidkonrad Not all badges are meant to be *hard*. They're there to encourage positive behaviour, which is clearly working in this case.

Comment: @AnnaLear Well, hmm, I like the challenge. I understand that the Marshall badge is an easy benefit from 10k tools. You _could_ say, that the flags we raise by the 10k-system not is included in the overall flag-"reputation"-account. Give us 1 rep per helpful flag instead. As my question goes, the credebility of the Marshal Badge is for me somehow ruined. Now I know, it is people who has more than 10k rep and using a few hours over a few days.

Comment: @davidkonrad Just because *you* got it that way doesn't mean others did, but you're certainly welcome to draw any conclusions you like. Either way, [the 10k flag queue is going away soon](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226092/lets-get-rid-of-the-10k-flag-queue) and this is a moot point.

Comment: @AnnaLear, "_Not all badges are meant to be hard._", well - make them harder. Or invent new badges. What should my goal be next? Besides becomimg "Legendary" which is out of my legaue, there is not that many badges left. I have eearlier suggested a new kind of badge after 10.000 reviews, it was rurned down immdiatelyy.

Comment: "rurned down" = turned down. "immdiatelyy" = immediately

Comment: @davidkonrad Good luck getting Marshal on a non-Stack Overflow site.

Comment: Troyen, your point is? I am talking about SO, not everything else. Your answer is exponent of the typical "meta" turbidity / straw man way-to-obstruct meme. Fine if you think I have made a stupid question, fair enough - but the llame comments are not very constructive. When you are not constructive, and not even fair - I cannot respond very constructive myself, being downvoted and bullyed at the same time. In danish we have a word : "You get answers as you cry in the wood". You dont want a debate, fair enough also - but, well - why even participate? Just for the chance for bullying?

Answer (score 4):

Gold badges don't have to be hard to get. On Mathoverflow, you can produce unlimited gold Publicist badges by posting links on reddit. Badges are just a nice way of getting people to work for free.

Answer (score 3):

A quick survey of the first 3 pages of the [Marshal Badges on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/badges/1298/marshal) (basically every one that was awarded in 2014, plus a couple from December 2013) shows that half of recently awarded have had reputations less than 10K.

Similarly, there are over 5500 10K+ users on Stack Overflow, and the Marshal badge has only been awarded 900 times, with a non-insignificant number of those users having less than 10K (including yours truly).

Those 2 facts together suggest that it is not to easy for everyone, or every badge hunter in the world who has 10K rep would have a Marshal badge.

Comment: It should also be pointed out that at first, the Marshal badge was awarded based on flag weight: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/103423/why-is-the-marshal-badge-awarded-at-a-flag-weight-of-749-and-not-at-750 , which made it a little harder to achieve since a single declined flag could kick your flag weight down a ways. It was changed to the current behavior a couple of years ago: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/119710/135615 , which I think makes it a little easier to get over time, particularly for those who indiscriminately flag everything in the 10k queue.